# tamperMonkey javascript setTimeout ID jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

why on all websites when i run tamperMonkey script with code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         My Fancy New Userscript2
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.google.com/
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==
var timer = 0;
function test() {
    console.log(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(test, 5000);
}
test();
```

the result is:

```
0
16
42
73
98
110
...
251
252
253
```

on local machine all fine, result is:

```
0
1
2
...
```

why on websites timer id so jump at start?

Comment: Because websites also set their timers.